# Response 501: 5.5.4 Invalid Address from email server

Tags: go, email

I'm testing my email client and I sent email for multiple servers, like outlook, gmail and guerrila email, but I receive 501: 5.5.4 as response. From what I understand it is some syntax error on my side, but I can't find it.

This is my test email:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: joe@mail.blmayer.dev
To: dzefinxo@sharklasers.com
Date: Sat, 21 Jan 2023 19:49:58 +0000
Subject: test
Message-ID: <sadfasdfasdfaerrrjoe@mail.blmayer.dev>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=87c47e1058b725db9b21bdecfb31391382ed3f4034dbc921fb183c13a3b2

--87c47e1058b725db9b21bdecfb31391382ed3f4034dbc921fb183c13a3b2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

test
--87c47e1058b725db9b21bdecfb31391382ed3f4034dbc921fb183c13a3b2--
```

This is the email body, I used Golang net/smtp SendMail function to send it. What is wrong in this?

Comment: You should probably start with the fact that those `From` and `To` are mail message header fields which are ignored by the SMTP server as they do not participate in the protocol; that is, the whole chunk of text you've presented is opaque to the SMTP protocol. Instead, it uses the so-called "envelope" addresses which are communicated by the client using SMTP commands during an SMTP session. I mean, start with checking whether you're passing sensbile parameters to the `net/smtp.SendMail` (that package does not have `SendEmail` FWIW).

Comment: Another point is that the server might just reject your attempt for reasons other than _the format_ of some of the addresses you're using being invalid. In theory, a server might want you to be authorized before sending mail so that it knows you're _allowed_ to send mail from the address you're using or from the domain of the sender address you're using; many servers which are not "open relays" do that because it's a sensible countermeasure against spammers. If a server is coded sloppily, it may use such a deceptive error status.

Comment: «start with checking whether you're passing sensbile parameters»—I mean that those `from` and `to` arguments to `SendMail` are what gets used as SMTP envelope addresses I referred to.

Comment: 501 5.5.4 means "Invalid command arguments" according to [RFC 3463](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463.html#section-3.6). It is unlikely that this is because of your mail. Unfortunately the actual details to debug the issue are missing. Please provide the actual code you are using which produces this error.

Comment: You got it @kostix! My To arg to SendMail was like this `append(to, cc)` but cc was an empty list, so the result was `["valid@email", ""]`, an empty element! Thank you!